# Bytefield inside an msc diagram

Tags: bytefield, msc

I'm trying to add a bytefield inside an msc diagram. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{msc}

\begin{document}
\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=1.5em, bitheight=1.5em]{4}
    \bitbox{1}{0} & \bitbox{1}{1} & \bitbox{1}[]{\dots} & \bitbox{1}{0}
\end{bytefield}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{msc}[instance distance=5cm]{}
        \declinst{alice}{Alice}{}
        \declinst{bob}{Bob}{}

        \nextlevel[5]
        \mess{
            \begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=1.5em, bitheight=1.5em]{4}
                \bitbox{1}{0} & \bitbox{1}{1} & \bitbox{1}[]{\dots} & \bitbox{1}{0}
            \end{bytefield}
        }{alice}{bob}
        \nextlevel[5]
    \end{msc}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Actually, this MWE gives an error: `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr`. I suppose this is due to msc, but I'm unsure how to solve it, and it may very well be the root of the problem. I've tried wrapping bytefield with braces or using parbox, but that didn't solve either.

The result is the following: the bytefield inside the diagram is on two lines instead of one.
[image]

I'd really appreciated some help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bytefield` environment doesn't like to be processed as the argument to another command. Here's a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{msc}

\newsavebox{\bfbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=1.5em, bitheight=1.5em]{4}
  \bitbox{1}{0} & \bitbox{1}{1} & \bitbox{1}[]{\dots} & \bitbox{1}{0}
\end{bytefield}

\begin{figure}

\begin{lrbox}{\bfbox}
  \begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=1.5em, bitheight=1.5em]{4}
    \bitbox{1}{0} & \bitbox{1}{1} & \bitbox{1}[]{\dots} & \bitbox{1}{0}
  \end{bytefield}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{msc}[instance distance=5cm]{}
  \declinst{alice}{Alice}{}
  \declinst{bob}{Bob}{}
  \nextlevel[5]
  \mess{\usebox{\bfbox}}{alice}{bob}
  \nextlevel[5]
\end{msc}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, define `sbytefield` (safe `bytefield`) to be used as argument to a command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{msc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{sbytefield}{O{}+b}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { & } { \cS\& } \l_tmpa_tl
  \zalessandro_bytefield:nV { #1 } \l_tmpa_tl
 }{}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \zalessandro_bytefield:nn
 {
  \begin{bytefield}[#1]#2\end{bytefield}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \zalessandro_bytefield:nn { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=1.5em, bitheight=1.5em]{4}
  \bitbox{1}{0} & \bitbox{1}{1} & \bitbox{1}[]{\dots} & \bitbox{1}{0}
\end{bytefield}

\begin{figure}

\begin{msc}[instance distance=5cm]{}
  \declinst{alice}{Alice}{}
  \declinst{bob}{Bob}{}
  \nextlevel[5]
  \mess{%
    \begin{sbytefield}[bitwidth=1.5em, bitheight=1.5em]{4}
      \bitbox{1}{0} & \bitbox{1}{1} & \bitbox{1}[]{\dots} & \bitbox{1}{0}
    \end{sbytefield}%
  }{alice}{bob}
  \nextlevel[5]
\end{msc}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The trick is that `bytefield` wants `&` to have category code 10 in its code and that's what the regex replacement does.

Comment: I was typing the exact same thing up... Too slow, you beat me by 35 seconds :(

Comment: @Skillmon On the other hand, since `msc` is based on Ti*k*Z, the bytefield might be emulated with a `pic`, perhaps.